# drag and drop a specific image to a specific panel and picture should not drop anywhere else except in that panel

Tags: unity

hi guys i'm building a drag and drop in unity and I have panels and images so for example I want the bank image to drop in the panel that has bank text in it and that image shouldn't drop anywhere else please help[image]

Comment: hmm did you try to have a parent Panels, then two children: a panel for the images and a panel for the images?

Comment: Which part are you hung up on?  The drag'n'drop portion, or constraining successful drops?

Comment: i do have two panels one for the images and another for the slots , it is dragging and dropping thats not the problem the actual problem is the area all my images drop at any slot witch is not wat i want

Answer (score 1):

Add a variable to check against before you can successfully drop the image. This could be of any number type (int, float, double) any type of string, or even a char. For example, assuming you used a string...

Give the bank panel a variable:

```
public const string panel_code = "bank";
```

Give the bank image the same string:

```
public const string image_code = "bank";
```

In the function that allows you to drop the image, first check:

```
if(image_code == panel_code)
{
    //Handle Image Drop Here
}
else
{
   //Handle (or don't handle) incorrect attempt here
}
```

Don't forget to adjust your private/public appropriately, and if you need it to be more dynamic, you will probably have to remove "const" and assign the string value using a function.

If you would like it to be a more rigid, predefined system with some additional typing benefits (a drop down box to ensure consistency and convenience); try using an enum in place of a string.

Without understanding more about how your code currently works, this is probably the best I can do to help.

Hope it does :)

Comment: Note that an enum is probably best suited for this. Checking against `ImageCode.Bank` has less margin of error and typos can be caught at compile time.  Not to mention it gives a nifty dropdown in the Inspector for easy configuration.

Comment: This is very true ketura! I'll add it to the answer. I think it depends on the amount of flexibility needed overall though.